# Error handler not catching Error

Tags: ms-access, vba

This issue I am having is my Error handler is not catching an error if it occurs more then 2 times. This is what im useing.

```
Private Sub DBBackUp()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
If FSO.FolderExists(DBBackupFolderDir) = True And FSO.FileExists(DBDir) = True Then

AskAgianLoop:

    Application.CompactRepair DBDir, CARDBBackupFileDir, True
End if


ErrHandler:
If Err.Number = 58 Or Err.Number = 31523 Then
    GoTo AskAgianLoop
Else
  errMsg = "Error number: " & Str(Err.Number) & vbNewLine & _
           "Source: " & Err.Source & vbNewLine & _
           "Description: " & Err.Description
Debug.Print errMsg
Err.Clear
End If
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

The above will prompt, with a security warning, the user 2 times each time its ran. If the user clicks cancel on one of them instead of open it will throw an error code with the value of `31523`. It is then moved to the ErrHandler. Which will then ask the user again with the same security prompt. If the user presses cancel more than 2 times an error message with the value of `31523` shows and does not get caught by the Error handler.

Comment: All explained clearly here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

Comment: @TimWilliams So `Resume` Would be a working solution instead of `GoTo AskAgianLoop`? In your link there is a section that says "you must ensure that your error handling block fixed the problem that caused the initial error. Otherwise, your code will enter an endless loop, jumping between the line of code that caused the error and the error handling block.". This is what I want to happen.

Comment: Don't you need some way to exit that loop, in case it gets stuck ?  You could add a counter, to exit after some number of tries...

Comment: @TimWilliams I want it to prompt them untill they click open. I just test `Resume` and it does get stuck in a loop and does not prompt agian. Not what I want to happen. How is `Resume <label>` used?

Comment: @TimWilliams `Resume AskAgianLoop:` Works perfectly. Thank you for the link.

Comment: Good to hear - I always forget exactly how it goes, and that's a good reference for checking my thoughts...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On Error goto <label> (incorrectly works)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364013/on-error-goto-label-incorrectly-works)

Comment: @YowE3K What did you seach for to find this? Edit: Never mind seen that it is your answer lol.

Comment: Yes - I remembered answering that question a day or two ago so I knew this question could definitely be classed as a duplicate of it.  There are a lot more that could be found by googling `site:stackoverflow.com excel-vba error handler not working`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `GoTo AskAgianLoop` to `Resume AskAgianLoop:` Fixed the issue.